# how to solve this problem org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I've been stuck at this problem for now more than 5 days

o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]

it doesn't let me create table in database.
I created many projects but it doesn't go away.

everything from the internet

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.